# If $P$ is a fg projective $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module, what is $P\otimes\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebraic-k-theory, projective-module, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $P$ a fg projective $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module. By a theorem of Swan, $P\otimes\mathbb{Q}\cong\mathbb{Q}[G]^n$ for some $n$. Is the same true for $\mathbb{R}$? Clearly, $(P\otimes\mathbb{R})^n$ is stably free (hence free) for some $n$ since $K_0(\mathbb{Z}[G])$ is finite (again by Swan), but I don't think this implies anything I want.

If $P\otimes\mathbb{R}$ isn't free, then can we say anything about it? Does it contain a factor of $\mathbb{R}[G]$, for example? I vaguely recall the rank of $P$ has to be some multiple of $|G|$ (once more by Swan) but can't remember where I read this.

Comment: $P \otimes \mathbb{R} = (P \otimes \mathbb{Q}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The comment above could have been provided as an answer, rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

[Comment reposted as an answer]:

We have $P \otimes \mathbb{R} = (P \otimes \mathbb{Q}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R}$.

Since $P \otimes \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q}[G]^n$ for some $n$, it follows that $P \otimes \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}[G]^n$.

Comment: Is this research level ?

Comment: @tj_ This appears to be a comment on the question, rather than my answer (unless you are suggesting that a different answer to this question would somehow have been "more research-level").